# Custom String class adding char* to it in c++

Tags: c++, string

I have a problem with my custom string operator += so that if I wanted to add a const char* to my custom string String, then it wouldn't add it, it would just be the String.  I can get it to work with other custom String objects but not with c strings.

code in String.cpp

```
String::String(){
    length =0;
    capacity = 1024;
    myStr = new char[0];
}
String::String (const String& s)
{
    length = s.getLength();
    myStr   = new char[length];
    for (unsigned j=0; j < length; j++){
        myStr[j] = s[j];
    }

}
String::String(char c){
    length = 1;
    myStr = new char(c);
}

String::String(const char* val){
    if(val!= nullptr){
        int counter = 0;
        while(val[counter]!='\0')counter++; //Find length of the char array
        length= counter;
        myStr = new char[counter];
        for(int i =0;i<counter;i++){
            myStr[i]=val[i];
        }


    }else{
        length = 1;
        myStr = new char[length];
        myStr[0] = '\0';
    }
}
ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const String& s)
{
    os<<s.myStr;

    return os;
}
istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, String& s)
{
    char* c = new char[1000];
    is >> c;
    s = String(c);
    delete[] c;

    return is;
}
String::~String(){
    delete[] myStr;
}
int String::getIndex(char getInd) const {
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
        if(myStr[i]==getInd){
            return i;
        }
    }
}
unsigned String::getLength() const{
    return length;

}
String& String::operator+= (const String& s){
    unsigned len = length+s.getLength();
    char* str=new char[len];
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
        str[i]=myStr[i];

    }
    for(int i = 0;i<s.length;i++){
        str[length+1]=s[i];
    }
    delete myStr;
    length = len;
    myStr= str;
    return *this;

}
String& String::operator+=(const char *c) {
    unsigned l =0;
    while(c[l] !='\0'){
        l++;
    }
    unsigned len =length+l;//new length of new string
    char* str = new char[len];
    for(int i = 0;i<getLength();i++) {
        str[i] = myStr[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j<l;j++){
        str[len+j]=c[j];
    }
    delete myStr;
    length = len;
    myStr = str;
    return *this;
}
String& String::operator=(const String& s){
    if(this == &s){
        return *this;
    }
    delete myStr;
    length = s.getLength();
    myStr = new char[length];
    for(int i = 0;i<length;i++){
        myStr[i]=s[i];
    }

}
char& String::operator[](unsigned i){
    if(i>=length) throw 1;
    return myStr[i];
}
char String::operator[] (unsigned j) const
{
    if (j >= length) throw 1;
    return myStr[j];
}
```

Code in main.cpp

```
int main() {

    
    

    char c[] = {'h','i'}


    
    String add = "iscool";
    String str="strworks";
    str+=add;
    str+=c;

    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The outcome for this program right now in the console is:

```
    
    strworks
```

I am not sure what to change about the const char* c += operator function, i believe this is where the error is.  I am also trying to use this string in a getline function but I try getline(file,String& s, ','); there is an error and I would appreciate any tips on how to implement the getline function with my new String class.  The String str should be histrworks in the second line of output, however it is blank.  I have already re written the logic of the += operator but it doesn't seem to be working. Let me know if there is any more information I need to give out that could assist you guys in finding the problem. The ultimate goal of this program is to read in a file of movie reviews and train an algorithim to find out if the review is positive/negative.

Comment: `str[length+1]=s[i];` - shouldn't that be `length + i`?  You want to write characters from `s` to successive locations in `str`....

Comment: sorry @TonyDelroy let me fix that, I was testing stuff but deleted it and forgot to re add it, ill edit the post now.

Comment: Good to boil it down to the relevant code.  `Hello, World!`, `fout`, `file` - none of that is relevant.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed that.

Comment: The debugger is your friend. You could easily trace through those functions and see what's happening. I'd run it myself if it was more of a [mcve].

Comment: When you append the character array, there is no '\0' character in there for the `+=` operator to use to detect the end of the text to append.  Consequently, you keep searching after the array, which gives your program undefined behaviour.

Comment: The debugger is why I had time to run Champions games a couple nights a week when I was in university. I highly recommend them.

Comment: This is wrong: `str[len + j] = c[j];` You probably want `length` instead of `len`. `myStr` is often not 0 terminated which is a problem based on how you use it in `operator<<`, and the mix of `unsigned` and `int` just leads to a bunch of compile warnings. Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: You need to decide whether you want your strings null-terminated or not, and if yes, whether "length" counts the null terminator. Right now you have a mix of both, and it cannot work well.

Comment: @TonyDelroy Thank you for your suggestion, I am sorry about lacking the knowledge but could you give an example of what that would look like in one of my String functions

Comment: @RetiredNinja Can you give me an example of how to null terminate myStr?